# Tool for smart card based PGP decryption?

Tags: windows, cryptography, pgp, smart-card

### My problem

(in case there's a solution I couldn't envision)

I want to build a secure backup solution. As I own [a smartcard](http://www.smartcard-hsm.com/), I thought to use asymmetric encryption with the private key remaining on the card for proper security. This would mean to use [duplicati](http://www.duplicati.com/), which supports [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) based encryption out of the box and thereby I can "hack" myself asymmetrically encrypted backups together. The only problem remaining is, that my smart card doesn't implement the [OpenPGP card standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenPGP_card) (only CSP and PKCS#11 via [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC)) and thereby I need an external tool to restore the files.

#### The resulting software requirements

- Must run on [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows) ([10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10))
- Must be able to [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse) and decrypt [OpenPGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenPGP) [encrypted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) [files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file)
- Must work with a [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Service_Provider) / [PKCS#11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_11) enabled [smartcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartcard)
- Must offer [command-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_line) based decryption
- May rely on other software (such as [PuTTY-CAC](https://risacher.org/putty-cac/))
- Should be free / [open-source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source)

#### The backup solution

I do have a Plan B, in case this goes wrong, which is to roll my own (really don't want that) and use [Peter Gutmann's cryptlib](http://www.cryptlib.com/) to do the job.

Comment: If you encrypt your backups with some public key, you don't need a smartcard at all. When wanting to decrypt then, it's becoming interesting maybe.