# Software for hardware enforced data backup?

Tags: backup, cryptography, smart-card

### The Problem

(may be skipped)

I'm thinking about transitioning to an improved backup solution in the long-term compared to what I did until now (which is documented [in my other question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/30858/19397)).
So in short, **I'm looking for a software that can do backups to various services / sites using strong encryption where the decryption keys reside in a [hardware security module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module)**.

### The specific requirements:

- Must support public key encryption of the data using public keys of any format (no restriction to [PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) key format especially)
- Must not need access to the decryption key during the backup process
- Must support at least basic backup targets ([FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP), [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS), [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), local filesystem)
- Must offer the option to sign the backups to avoid fraudelent data being restored
- Must run on common [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) distributions or [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows) ([10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10))
- Really should run on Windows (10)
- Really should support usual backup targets ([S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_S3), [Glacier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Glacier), [OneDrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OneDrive), [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive), ...)
- Really should support hardware based decryption (via either [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Cryptography_Extension), [PKCS#11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_11), [CAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Application_Programming_Interface) or [CNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography_API:_Next_Generation)) for data restoration
- Should offer a way to let the signature key reside in hardware (and just gets the PIN supplied) and access the hardware via either Java, PKCS#11, CAPI or CNG
- May offer assistance (specific [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUI)) for the [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) operations for certifying signature keys allowed for backups
- May offer a GUI for managing the backups (config files and command line are also OK)
- May be open-source
- If not open-source, price isn't an issue (the hardware will be *much* more expensive anyways)
- Security audits / security certifications are a bonus, but not a requirement